# nested selector failed in using simple html dom parser

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I want to get the link and scrape its content but I can';t event reach there. What's wrong with my nested selector?

my php

```
$dom = file_get_html('http://mojim.com/%E5%BF%83%E8%B7%B3.html?t3');

$tables = $dom->find('.iB');
$firstRow = $tables->find('tr',1)->find('td',4);

foreach ($firstRow as $value) {
    echo $value;
 } 

 ?>
```

here is how the DOM look like
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a problem on pointing/traversing the correct element.

Example:

```
$dom = file_get_html('http://mojim.com/%E5%BF%83%E8%B7%B3.html?t3');
$firstRow = $dom->find('table.iB', 0)->find('tr', 1)->find('td', 3);
$link = $firstRow->find('a', 0);
echo $link->href . '<br/>' . $link->title;
```

Should output:

```
/twy100015x34x8.htm
心跳 歌詞 王力宏
```